# How to make sure a user only gets added to a list once

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2007

I have to list a list of users through a custom search, where I take all the users from all the groups added to the permissions list on the sharepoint web. My issue is that users can be in several groups, thus they get added multiple times to the list that gets returned. How do I make sure they only gets added once?

### **C#**

```
// keywords is the whatever value a user types into the search textbox
private static IEnumerable<SPUser> GetUsers(SPWeb web, string keywords)
    {
        var oList = new List<SPUser>();
        var oListUsers = web.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().SelectMany(grp => grp.Users.Cast<SPUser>().Where(user => user.Name.Contains(keywords))).ToList();

        foreach (SPUser user in oListUsers)
        {
            // My attempt here is to check if the list already contains the current item
            // but it seems to ignore it. I've tried counting too, but same outcome.
            if (!oList.Contains(user))
                oList.Add(user);
        }

        return oList;
    }
```

Comment: oList.Contains(user) returns false even if user is in that list?

Comment: .Contains() does a reference check if the type is a reference type and would return false if oList does not contain a reference to the same object referenced by the current iteration of user.  However, you can override the .Equals() method in the class to force a specific comparison (on the user.Name property, for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (instead of contains)

```
 if (! oList.Any(u => u.Name == user.Name ))
 {
      oList.Add(user);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your SPUser class needs to implement `IEquatable<SPUser>` for contains to work as you want it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq to get unique records

```
var uniqueValues = oList.Distinct();
```

This will remove `SPUser` object with same reference. Also you can implement `IEqualityCompaprer<SPUser>` for your own equlity logic

Answer (score 3):

Use a Hashset instead of a List.  That way, you don't have to check for containment, and duplicate items will just be ignored.

This will be faster too, as the HashSet is able to reject duplicates almost trivially, while the List<>.Contains() is O(n)

```
 var oList = new HashSet<SPUser>();
    var oListUsers = web.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().SelectMany(grp => grp.Users.Cast<SPUser> ().Where(user => user.Name.Contains(keywords))).ToList();

    foreach (SPUser user in oListUsers)
    {
      oList.Add(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By brute force, you could just use Distinct:

```
var oListUsers = web.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().SelectMany(grp => grp.Users.Cast<SPUser>().Where(user => user.Name.Contains(keywords))).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have different objects in your `oListUsers` list that represent the same user, but have different object references - since `Contains()` uses object references to check, you won't be able to catch this case unless you define a custom comparer / Equality on your `SPUser` class.

Alternatively if i.e. the user name is unique  you could filter out duplicates that way.